# Gap under footer - sticky footer?

Tags: css, footer

I have a demo here to illustrate my question.

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/

It's a header, content and a footer. 
The content is pushing the footer below the window but the footer still has a gap below.

Why is there a gap below the footer?

Do I need a sticky footer?

What's the best sticky footer for a responsive layout?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title of the document</title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <meta name="robots" content="">


      <style type="text/css">

        /* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
           v2.0b1 | 201101 
           NOTE: WORK IN PROGRESS
           USE WITH CAUTION AND TEST WITH ABANDON */

        html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
        a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
        del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
        small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
        b, u, i, center,
        dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
        fieldset, form, label, legend,
        table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
        article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
        footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
        time, mark, audio, video {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            outline: 0;
            font-size: 100%;
            font: inherit;
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }
        /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
        article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
        footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
            display: block;
        }
        body {
            line-height: 1;
        }
        ol, ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
        blockquote, q {
            quotes: none;
        }
        blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
        q:before, q:after {
            content: '';
            content: none;
        }

        /* remember to define visible focus styles! 
        :focus {
            outline: ?????;
        } */

        /* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
        ins {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        del {
            text-decoration: line-through;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        /* CLEAR FIX */

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        .group:after {
            content: ".";
              display: block;
              height: 0;
              clear: both;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        *html .group {
            height:1%;
        }

        *:first-child+html .group {
            min-height: 1px;
        }

        .clear {
            clear:both;
        }

        /* END CLEAR FIX */


        body{
            font:1em Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        #page{
            max-width:1000px;
            margin:0 auto;
        }   

        header{
            background:blue;
            height:100px;
        }

        .pageContent{
            padding:50px 0;
            background:#eee;
        }

        footer{
            background:#b5b6b9;
            width:1000px;
            margin:0 auto;
        }

        footer ul{
            float:left;
            margin:0 20px 0 0;
        }
        footer ul li:first-of-type a{
            text-transform:uppercase;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        footer a{
            display:inline-block;
            color:white;
            font-size:.8em;
            padding:1px;
        }


      </style>

      </head>

    <body>

        <div id="page">

          <header class="group">
            <h2>Header</h2>
          </header>  

            <section class="pageContent">
                <h2>Content</h2>
                  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            </section>


      <footer class="group">
        <h2>Footer</h2>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2-3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2-4</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3-3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3-4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3-5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3-6</a></li>
            </ul>

      </footer>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: First thing is to validate your code and make sure all your tags are properly closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this:

```
.group::after {
  height: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The only sticky footer I have ever seen working 100% of the time, was this one: http://jsfiddle.net/DU3uf/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>

        </header>
        <section>

        </section>
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { width:100%; height:100%; }
#wrapper { width:100%; min-height:100%; height:auto; margin:0 auto -100px; }
#wrapper > header { width:100%; height:100px; background-color:#333; }
#wrapper > section { width:100%; height:400px; background-color:#FFF; }
#push { width:100%; height:100px; clear:both; }
footer { width:100%; height:100px; background-color:#1BA1E2; }
```

It's the same used by bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
.group::after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Remove this `height: 0;`

Comment: The height:0; is from the clear fix I have used for a while now, can't remember where I got it. Does the clear fix need the height:0;